# How Python zipFile module unzipfile keep file last modified time?

Tags: python, gzip, unzip, python-zipfile

```
z1 = zipfile.ZipFile('path\Test.zip')
z1.extractall('path\Test')
z1.close()
```

When I use zipfile of Python to unzip a zip file, the date modified of all files will become the unzip time now.

How to keep the date modified not change when unzip?

Other language like C# has API to keep not change the date modified